# SImple present answer for simple past question?

Tags: grammar

I read a book about the Taj Mahal. They have a question and an answer:

> What materials were used to make it?
>
> It is made of white marble.

I wonder if a simple present answer for a simple past question is correct or not? In my opinion, it's correct since the answer is a truth - Taj Mahal is made of white marble.

Hope to receive your answers.

Comment: "Correct" does not apply.  Your response would be understood to mean that marble was the original material, but not because of any specific feature of the English language.

Comment: *I wonder if a simple present answer for a simple past question is grammatically correct or not?*

Comment: There is nothing in the *grammar* that requires your answer to be in a particular tense, based on the tense of the question.  "Can you swim? -- I am taking swimming lessons. I have taken swimming lessons. I took swimming lessons. I will be taking swimming lessons. I wish I had taken swimming lessons...."    None of the replies is "yes" or "no", so none would satisfy a lawyer in a court of law.  But they're all grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

Answering using either

> It is made of white marble.
>   It was made with white marble.

would both be correct, since the Taj Mahal is still made of the same white marble.
You can do this if *something* is continuing/ongoing or habitual.

The same would be for

> Have you been to the seaside?
>   I go every summer.
>
> Have you ever played baseball?
>   I play every Saturday morning with my team.

Comment: does it mean that I can use simple present in this case without creating any ambiguous meaning?

Comment: There is no ambiguity saying "It is made of white marble." as long as the original question is also present to give context. On it's own, "It is made of white marble" may be ambiguous if one might think the Taj Mahal was renovated between the time it was first built and when this answer is given.